# set и unordered_set

Tags: c++

Все мы знаем, что std::set - это красно-чёрное дерево (соответственно со сложностью поиска O(log n)), а std::unordered_set - хэш-таблица с поиском за константу.
Какие вообще преимущества есть у set'а, не считая поддержание порядка элементов? Если мне не важен порядок, то *всегда ли* лучше выбрать хэш-таблицу?

Comment: сет чуть меньше памяти использует, и надёжнее. Хеш таблица - штука вероятностная всё же. А в целом - да, хеш - таблица обычно лучше.

Comment: Ну, например, перерасход памяти. Возможно, не подходящая (или неудачно написанная для пользовательских данных) хэш-функция, так что данные плохо хэшируются. Как всегда, нужно экспериментировать - панацеи не существует...

Comment: из того, что я читал, реализация unorderd_set использует выделение памяти мелкими кусками (как связанный список), и при большой нагрузке будет фрагментировать память.

Comment: @KoVadim это как?... Как тогда получать доступ за O(1) если память кусками

Answer (score 3):

Иногда,хранение именно в виде упорядоченного массива очень важно с точки зрения алгоритма. Например, найдите значение (int), ближайшее к заданному, если значения хранятся в unodered_set.

Иногда, написание адекватной задаче хеш функции - невозможно, например, при хранении double.

Иногда, ожидаемый набор данных достаточно мал. О(1) не всегда быстрее O(Log(n)), можно гарантировать только, что существует такой размер набора данных, на котором O(1) будет быстрее. На практике, часто встречаются ситуации, когда ожидаемое число значений 3-5 штук.

Также следует помнить, что стоимость одного вычисления хеша для строки O(k) (где k -длинна строки) - в среднем, а стоимость оператора сравнения O(k) - в худшем случае и O(log(n)) - в среднем, если строи случайные начиная с первых символов. При этом, в случае set будет произведено только одно "неудачное" сравнение, когда мы найдем искомый результат, но это дорогое сравнение на придется произвести и в случае unordered_set. Если ожидаемый набор строк для поиска, только с очень маленькой вероятностью содержит строки из set, то O(k) окажется дороже O(log(n)).